# Postman CLI integrated with jenkins console output not very readable

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, postman, console.log

[90m--------------------------[39m[90m--------------------[39m[90m---------------------[39m
[90m|[39m                         [90m|[39m          executed [90m|[39m            failed [90m|[39m
[90m--------------------------[39m[90m+-------------------[39m[90m+--------------------[39m
[90m|[39m              iterations [90m|[39m                 1 [90m|[39m                 0 [90m|[39m
[90m--------------------------[39m[90m+-------------------[39m[90m+--------------------[39m
[90m|[39m                requests [90m|[39m                 7 [90m|[39m                 0 [90m|[39m
[90m--------------------------[39m[90m+-------------------[39m[90m+--------------------[39m
[90m|[39m            test-scripts [90m|[39m                 7 [90m|[39m                 0 [90m|[39m
[90m--------------------------[39m[90m+-------------------[39m[90m+--------------------[39m
[90m|[39m      prerequest-scripts [90m|[39m                 1 [90m|[39m                 0 [90m|[39m
[90m--------------------------[39m[90m+-------------------[39m[90m+--------------------[39m
[90m|[39m              assertions [90m|[39m                19 [90m|[39m                 8 [90m|[39m
[90m-------------------------------------------------------------------[39m
[90m|[39m total run duration: 826ms                                       [90m|[39m
[90m-------------------------------------------------------------------[39m
[90m|[39m total data received: 16.63kB (approx)                           [90m|[39m
[90m-------------------------------------------------------------------[39m
[90m|[39m average response time: 87ms [min: 6ms, max: 312ms, s.d.: 108ms] [90m|[39m
[90m-------------------------------------------------------------------[39m

I´m expecting the following one [Postman example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TkcQ.png)